# What is causing that buzz when running my mini-split air conditioner?

Tags: air-conditioning, mini-split

There is a short buzz noise that emanates randomly while running my GREE mini-split air conditioner.  At first I thought it occurs only while running one of the 3 units, but it seems to occur when running one of the other units independently too.  Leads me to suspect that the issue is in the condenser unit located outside on the deck rather than the condensate pump in the units.  BTW, is it possible to attach a recording of the buzz on this website?

Comment: Why are you excluding the condensate pump hypothesis? Each of your indoor units most likely has a pump.

Comment: @TvE Actually, I determined that the buzz was coming from one of the condensate pumps that are installed in the attic.  It turns out that the pump causing the buzz was installed directly onto the ceiling joist and was missing the rubber mat that is meant to dampen the noise when it's running.  Although the other two pumps were mounted on their rubber mats and thereby not causing a buzz, I decided to hang all three pumps from the ceiling rafters.  It's been a year since this was done and have not had any buzzing issues when the pumps are running!